# JavaScript stragegy pattern with dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, strategy-pattern

In C# I use strategy pattern with dictionary like this:

```
namespace NowListeningParserTool.Classes
{
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class WebsiteDictionary
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, WebsiteParser> _website = new Dictionary<string, WebsiteParser>();

    public WebsiteDictionary()
    {
        _website.Add("YouTube", new YoutubeWebsiteParser());
        _website.Add("977 Music", new NineNineSevenMusicWebsiteParser());
        _website.Add("Grooveshark", new GroovesharkWebsiteParser());
        _website.Add("Sky.FM", new SkyfmWebsiteParser());
        _website.Add("iHeart", new IheartWebsiteParser());
        _website.Add("Live365", new LiveThreeSixFiveWebsiteParser());
        _website.Add("Pandora", new PandoraWebsiteParser());
        _website.Add("Spotify", new SpotifyWebsiteParser());
    }

    public string GetArtistAndTitle(string website, string browser, string stringToParse)
    {
        return _website[website].GetArtistAndTitle(browser, stringToParse, website);
    }

    public string GetWebsiteLogoUri(string website)
    {
        return _website[website].WebsiteLogoUri;
    }
}
}
```

WebsiteParser is abstract class.

What would be the syntax for this in JavaScript? For example I have multiple IF statements in JavaScript:

```
function getWebsite() {
    if (document.URL.indexOf('grooveshark.com') >= 0) return getTrackGrooveshark();
    if (document.URL.indexOf('977music.com') >= 0) return getTrack977Music();
    if (document.URL.indexOf('sky.fm/play') >= 0) return getTrackSkyFm();
    if (document.URL.indexOf('iheart.com') >= 0) return getTrackIHeart();
    if (document.URL.indexOf('live365.com') >= 0) return getTrackLive365();
    if (document.URL.indexOf('youtube.com') >= 0) return getTrackYoutube();
    if (document.URL.indexOf('pandora.com') >= 0) return getTrackPandora();
    if (document.URL.indexOf('spotify.com') >= 0) return getTrackSpotify();
}
```

...that I really don't like, and would like to use the same approach as I did in C# for eliminating these ugly IFs.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not really sure how the C# code you have eliminates the need for the if statements...?  If I understand correctly, you have a URL and you're looking for a specific string in it, which leads to a decision tree.  For example, to use your C# code, wouldn't you have to write `if( someUrl.Contains("grooveshark.com") ) return websiteDictionary.GetArtistAndTitle( "Grooveshark", browser, someUrl );`?

Comment: I would add that whatever you want to do with polymorphism in C# (as in your dictionary pattern) you can absolutely do in JavaScript, as it's actually MORE flexible than C# in this regard, not less.  Furthermore, JavaScript may offer an even more DRY approach...I think you just need to describe what you're after a little better.

Comment: Ethan you are correct, I decide by website name to which dictionary item should be invoked as you have written. This is the usage then in viewmodels(wpf) for example `songName = _website.GetArtistAndTitle(website, browser, songName);` where website parameter is the parameter which decides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, but I dont have enough details to know if this approach will work or not for you. However, it shows how to use objects as key/value stores.

```
var fetchingStrategies = {
    'grooveshark.com': function () {
        return 'grooving!';
    },
    'youtube.com': function () {
        return 'youtubing!';
    }
};

//execute fetching strategy based on domain
fetchingStrategies['youtube.com']();
```

Obviously you can replace the hard-coded 'youtube.com' string by a variable that would hold the correct domain for the lookup.

Comment: I really really like this clean approach, but how does this work if I have to check the current domain and then decide what to invoke? For example if I get current domain with `window.location.host`, you know what i mean? your example only invokes if you set direct value, which means i would have to format my domain to direct value for this to work or is there other approach for this particular example than formatting? Thanks

Comment: @JohnMathilda I am not sure that I see a problematic here. What is the value passed as `website` in your examples? `window.location.hostname` would give the domain of the current host, so you can just do `fetchingStrategies[location.hostname]` to get the correct fetching strategy.

Comment: I agree, I forgot that you have an option for direct domain. thanks i will try it in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Returns the content from the executed function.

```
function getWebsite() {
    var websites = [
            ['grooveshark.com',getTrackGrooveshark],
            ['977music.com',getTrack977Music],
            ['sky.fm/play',getTrackSkyFm],
            ['iheart.com',getTrackIHeart],
            ['live365.com',getTrackLive365],
            ['youtube.com',getTrackYoutube],
            ['pandora.com',getTrackPandora],
            ['spotify.com',getTrackSpotify]
        ],
        url = document.URL,
        ret;
    $.each(websites,function(i,v){
        if(url.indexOf(v[0]) !== -1){
           ret = v[1]();
           return false;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Option 2: Invoke the function.. Return Nothing

```
function getWebsite() {
    var websites = [
            ['grooveshark.com',getTrackGrooveshark],
            ['977music.com',getTrack977Music],
            ['sky.fm/play',getTrackSkyFm],
            ['iheart.com',getTrackIHeart],
            ['live365.com',getTrackLive365],
            ['youtube.com',getTrackYoutube],
            ['pandora.com',getTrackPandora],
            ['spotify.com',getTrackSpotify]
        ],
        url = document.URL;

    $.each(websites,function(i,v){
        if(url.indexOf(v[0]) !== -1){
           v[1](); //Executes the function
           return false; //Breaks the Each loop.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No need for anonymous functions: `['iheart.com', getTrackIHeart]`

Comment: Thank you. I have a question, since I am not the best in JS, does this mean that fn saves the value that is returned from function? v[1] actually invokes function? Thanks!

Comment: the function reference is returned.  If you just wanted to execute the function replace return fn; with if(fn)fn();

Comment: I mean what is the value in `fn`? Result from v[1], which is the executed function(getTrackGrooveshark,...)? thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for option 1.  I didn't realize the called functions had a return value.  Option 1 now returns the value from the executed callback fn.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is really a matter of using a simple JavaScript object. Basically you can reference any property of an object in a similar fashion as you are doing in C#, but I think in a much simpler way. Of course that is my opinion :)  I like to structure my modules in a self instantiating manner, like jQuery, so there may be more here than you need in the simplest form. I am also going to assume your parsers are global methods for the example's sake, but you should avoid doing that in real practice. Sorry for any typos as I am doing this in the WYSIWYG editor here.

Here goes:

(function () {

```
"use strict";

var WebsiteDictionary = function () {

    return new WebsiteDictionary.fn.init();
};

WebsiteDictionary.fn = WebsiteDictionary.prototype = {

    constructor: WebsiteDictionary,

    init: function () {

         this._website["YouTube"] = YoutubeWebsiteParser();
         this._website["977Music"] = NineNineSevenMusicWebsiteParser();
         this._website["Grooveshark"] = GroovesharkWebsiteParser();
         this._website["SkyFM"] = SkyfmWebsiteParser();
         this._website["iHeart"] = IheartWebsiteParser();
         this._website["Live365"] = LiveThreeSixFiveWebsiteParser();
         this._website["Pandora"] = PandoraWebsiteParser();
         this._website["Spotify"] = SpotifyWebsiteParser();

        return this;
    },

   _website: {},


   GetArtistAndTitle: function(website, browser, stringToParse)
   {
      return this._website[website].GetArtistAndTitle(browser, stringToParse, website);
   }

   GetWebsiteLogoUri: function(website)
   {
      return this._website[website].WebsiteLogoUri;
   }


};


// Give the init function the love2DevApp prototype for later instantiation
WebsiteDictionary.fn.init.prototype = WebsiteDictionary.fn;

return (window.WebsiteDictionary= WebsiteDictionary);
```

}());

I believe this is called an associative array, but don't quote me on that. Basically every member/property of a JavaScript object is accessible in a similar fashion as you access the Dictionary properties in C#. So the member's name is the dictionary key. I also edited the names so they can be valid JavaScript names.

I hope this helps. I think this is a pretty nifty little JavaScript technique. If you review some high profile JavaScript libraries, like jQuery you see this being used a lot.

Comment: Way too verbose for nothing in my opinion. That whole `.fn` thing is totally useless. The same applies to an `init` function, since you already have a constructor function, just use it. `init` is useful when you are using object literals and `Object.create`.

Comment: sorry you feel that way. Find making a self instantiating, easily extensible object to be extremely useful.

Comment: I am just saying that there are simpler ways to implement an object as extensible, flexible and reusable as the sample you provided. Also in your example, the `_website` object will be shared across all instances, so there is no point to initialize it every time `init` is called.

Comment: you are correct, normally I nest them in the prototype. Again I was typing off the top of my head int eh WYSWYG editor :>